# PHP: Previous Month from current month formula is not working

Tags: php

It might be Duplicate Question, but I tried but it doesn't work.
Something confusion is there, which I am not getting it.I tried for all months its working but its not working for "March" Month.I know it sound weird, but I tried everything.

Aim: Show Previous Month from Given Month.

PHP:

```
$month='March';
$pre_mth =Date("F", strtotime($month . " last month"));
echo $pre_mth;

Actual Output: March    Expected Output:February
```

Please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pre_mth = date('F',strtotime('first day of last month', strtotime($month)));
echo $pre_mth;
```

Comment: Its working, but how its possible until yesterday it was working and now its not working.

Answer (score -1):

Extra space existed before "last month". Also, specify a day to avoid conflicts.

Try this:

```
$month = 'March 1';
$pre_mth = Date("F", strtotime($month . "last month"));
echo $pre_mth; // February
```

Comment: I tried that too, its showing the January as Output.

Comment: Even with 'March 1' ?

Comment: Great, then you can upvote & mark the answer as right ^__^.